# Using NLP to Find Commonly Occurring Job Qualifications

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence

I have a list of jobs where each job has a list of qualifications. I want to be able to find qualifications that are commonly listed together with a qualification q. For example, if there are jobs A [Python,Java,C++], B [Java,C++], C [Word,Excel], then I want to be able to determine that Java is most commonly needed in jobs where C++ is also needed, and Python less so. What is the formal name of this NLP problem, and what algorithms can I use to solve this problem?

Comment: Please read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is an NLP problem. You can solve this by formulating an information matrix for each skill. See Pointwise Mutual Information https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_mutual_information